# Magento 2 Admin Error

Tags: magento2, database

I got the error "There has been an error processing your request" while trying to access the M2 backend. It happened because I set the session timeout beyond "9999." Its just a dev site now so I would like to hold it open while Im working. Where is that info stored in the database so I can change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be in the core_config_data table under a path of admin/security/session_lifetime

You will need to clear cache afterwards.

Comment: Same as 1.x. I should have been more thorough. Thank You for your direction.